# Disable spring boot actuator "health-component" and "health-component-instance"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Hi I am using actuator in sprinb-boot 2, with the following properties

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
```

My aim is to disable all endpoints except health. By this configuration I disabled all except health and getting the following endpoints now  `"health", "health-component", "health-component-instance"` . Is it possible to disable `"health-component", "health-component-instance"` as well ? And how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Health component endpoints were introduced in [Spring Boot 2.2.0.M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b51b997b70bbb7ffc5b2291fd6309acb55dd3f31) as an extension to already existing [`HealthEndpoint`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthEndpoint.java).

There is no configuration option to disable just `/health-component` and `/health-component-instance`, either the entire `health` endpoint is disabled or not.

Answer (score 2):

For SpringBoot 2.1.3 you can use the following in you application.yml:

```
#ENDPOINTS:
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - 'health'
        - 'info'
```

It will make only two listed endpoints available from actuator.

Comment: actually, as you can see from question I did the same , but with health , also  "health-component", "health-component-instance" up as well

Comment: Not exactly. In SpringBoot2 there are two concepts about default endpoints: enabling and exposed for JMX or Web. Notice I use web.exposure.include  domain in my config.

Comment: sorry , yes :) , I just tried management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
this give the same result as 
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
is there best practice wich to use ? or which is preferable and why "?

Comment: It was a big security issue with Spring Actuator in previous version with default endpoints, so they reimplement them and make them closed for web by default. Currently, they recommend open only what is needed with some extra definitions via  extensions like:  @EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint.class)
public class HealthWebExtension { . ...

Answer (score 1):

add in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add a config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health/*").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using reactive web , I guess this will not work , but idea yes will work ! thanks